# Add string Column B where string exists in column Columns A + np.where() + pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, numpy

I need to add a secondary ID in a dataset with unique entries for multiple individuals. To do so I am trying to use `np.where()`, after I implemented I realized I am overwriting the last entry each time. This an example of the original approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Example':['1','2','3','4']})

df['Add'] = ''

df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example']== '1', 'One','')
df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example']== '2', 'Two','')
df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example']== '3', 'Three','')
df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example']== '4', 'Four','')

df.head()
```

As a work around I tried adding `str.contains('')` thinking that would evaluate `True` when string is empty and only insert new string in that case. As below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Example':['1','2','3','4']})

df['Add'] = ''

df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example'].str.contains('')== '1', 'One','')
df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example'].str.contains('')== '2', 'Two','')
df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example'].str.contains('')== '3', 'Three','')
df['Add'] = np.where(df['Example'].str.contains('')== '4', 'Four','')

df.head()
```

In that instance everything is being filled with an empty string...

Is there a simple method to check if a cell is empty before writing with `np.where()`?

Comment: The problem is that the second `np.where()` replaces all the `One` values with `''`.

Comment: I realize that, that's what I'm trying to address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
dmap = {'1': 'One', '2': 'Two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four'}

df['Add']  = df['Example'].map(dmap).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Example    Add
0       1    One
1       2    Two
2       3  Three
3       4   Four
```